New messsage "Active checkers" in cppcheck after upgrade
I integrate cppcheck analysis with CMake by specifying this command line:
cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_CXX_CPPCHECK="cppcheck;--enable=all;--suppress=missingIncludeSystem;--inline-suppr;--std=c++17;--error-exitcode=1"

and works well.
After upgrading my Ubuntu, with cppcheck version 2.13.0, I started seeing this extra message/warning:
...
[89/108] Building CXX object include/boost/multi/adaptors/fftw/test/CMakeFiles/combinations.cpp.x.dir/combinations.cpp.o
Checking /home/user/boost-multi/include/boost/multi/adaptors/fftw/test/combinations.cpp ...
nofile:0:0: information: Active checkers: 4/592 (use --checkers-report=<filename> to see details) [checkersReport]
...

For every target!
What is the meaning of this message "Active checkers: 4/592"? Why 4?
The help says,
$ cppcheck --help
...
    --checkers-report=<file>
                         Write a report of all the active checkers to the given file.
...

But it doesn't help me understand.
When I add the option --checkers-report=cppcheck.report, I get the following file
$ cat ./.build.g++.plus/cppcheck.report
Critical errors
---------------
No critical errors, all files were checked.
Important: Analysis is still not guaranteed to be 'complete' it is possible there are false negatives.


Open source checkers
--------------------
No   Check64BitPortability::pointerassignment                  require:portability
No   CheckAssert::assertWithSideEffects                        require:warning
No   CheckAutoVariables::assignFunctionArg                     require:style,warning
No   CheckAutoVariables::autoVariables
No   CheckAutoVariables::checkVarLifetime
No   CheckBool::checkAssignBoolToFloat                         require:style,c++
No   CheckBool::checkAssignBoolToPointer
No   CheckBool::checkBitwiseOnBoolean                          require:style,inconclusive
No   CheckBool::checkComparisonOfBoolExpressionWithInt         require:warning
No   CheckBool::checkComparisonOfBoolWithBool                  require:style,c++
No   CheckBool::checkComparisonOfBoolWithInt                   require:warning,c++
No   CheckBool::checkComparisonOfFuncReturningBool             require:style,c++
No   CheckBool::checkIncrementBoolean                          require:style
No   CheckBool::pointerArithBool
No   CheckBool::returnValueOfFunctionReturningBool             require:style
No   CheckBoost::checkBoostForeachModification
Yes  CheckBufferOverrun::analyseWholeProgram
No   CheckBufferOverrun::argumentSize                          require:warning
No   CheckBufferOverrun::arrayIndex
No   CheckBufferOverrun::arrayIndexThenCheck
No   CheckBufferOverrun::bufferOverflow
No   CheckBufferOverrun::negativeArraySize
No   CheckBufferOverrun::objectIndex
No   CheckBufferOverrun::pointerArithmetic                     require:portability
No   CheckBufferOverrun::stringNotZeroTerminated               require:warning,inconclusive
Yes  CheckClass::analyseWholeProgram
No   CheckClass::checkConst                                    require:style,inconclusive
No   CheckClass::checkConstructors                             require:style,warning
No   CheckClass::checkCopyConstructors                         require:warning
No   CheckClass::checkDuplInheritedMembers                     require:warning
No   CheckClass::checkExplicitConstructors                     require:style
No   CheckClass::checkMemset
No   CheckClass::checkMissingOverride                          require:style,c++03
No   CheckClass::checkSelfInitialization
No   CheckClass::checkThisUseAfterFree                         require:warning
No   CheckClass::checkUnsafeClassRefMember                     require:warning,safeChecks
No   CheckClass::checkUselessOverride                          require:style
No   CheckClass::checkVirtualFunctionCallInConstructor         require:warning
No   CheckClass::initializationListUsage                       require:performance
No   CheckClass::initializerListOrder                          require:style,inconclusive
No   CheckClass::operatorEqRetRefThis                          require:style
No   CheckClass::operatorEqToSelf                              require:warning
No   CheckClass::privateFunctions                              require:style
No   CheckClass::thisSubtraction                               require:warning
No   CheckClass::virtualDestructor
No   CheckCondition::alwaysTrueFalse                           require:style
No   CheckCondition::assignIf                                  require:style
No   CheckCondition::checkAssignmentInCondition                require:style
No   CheckCondition::checkBadBitmaskCheck                      require:style
No   CheckCondition::checkCompareValueOutOfTypeRange           require:style,platform
No   CheckCondition::checkDuplicateConditionalAssign           require:style
No   CheckCondition::checkIncorrectLogicOperator               require:style,warning
No   CheckCondition::checkInvalidTestForOverflow               require:warning
No   CheckCondition::checkModuloAlwaysTrueFalse                require:warning
No   CheckCondition::checkPointerAdditionResultNotNull         require:warning
No   CheckCondition::clarifyCondition                          require:style
No   CheckCondition::comparison                                require:style
No   CheckCondition::duplicateCondition                        require:style
No   CheckCondition::multiCondition                            require:style
No   CheckCondition::multiCondition2                           require:warning
No   CheckExceptionSafety::checkCatchExceptionByValue          require:style
No   CheckExceptionSafety::checkRethrowCopy                    require:style
No   CheckExceptionSafety::deallocThrow                        require:warning
No   CheckExceptionSafety::destructors                         require:warning
No   CheckExceptionSafety::nothrowThrows
No   CheckExceptionSafety::rethrowNoCurrentException
No   CheckExceptionSafety::unhandledExceptionSpecification     require:style,inconclusive
No   CheckFunctions::checkIgnoredReturnValue                   require:style,warning
No   CheckFunctions::checkMathFunctions                        require:style,warning,c99,c++11
No   CheckFunctions::checkMissingReturn
No   CheckFunctions::checkProhibitedFunctions
No   CheckFunctions::invalidFunctionUsage
No   CheckFunctions::memsetInvalid2ndParam                     require:warning,portability
No   CheckFunctions::memsetZeroBytes                           require:warning
No   CheckFunctions::returnLocalStdMove                        require:performance,c++11
No   CheckFunctions::useStandardLibrary                        require:style
No   CheckIO::checkCoutCerrMisusage                            require:c
No   CheckIO::checkFileUsage
No   CheckIO::checkWrongPrintfScanfArguments
No   CheckLeakAutoVar::check                                   require:notclang
No   CheckMemoryLeakInClass::check
No   CheckMemoryLeakInFunction::checkReallocUsage
No   CheckMemoryLeakNoVar::check
No   CheckMemoryLeakStructMember::check
Yes  CheckNullPointer::analyseWholeProgram
No   CheckNullPointer::arithmetic
No   CheckNullPointer::nullConstantDereference
No   CheckNullPointer::nullPointer
No   CheckOther::checkAccessOfMovedVariable                    require:c++11,warning
No   CheckOther::checkCastIntToCharAndBack                     require:warning
No   CheckOther::checkCharVariable                             require:warning,portability
No   CheckOther::checkComparePointers
No   CheckOther::checkComparisonFunctionIsAlwaysTrueOrFalse    require:warning
No   CheckOther::checkConstPointer                             require:style
No   CheckOther::checkDuplicateBranch                          require:style,inconclusive
No   CheckOther::checkDuplicateExpression                      require:style,warning
No   CheckOther::checkEvaluationOrder                          require:C/C++03
No   CheckOther::checkFuncArgNamesDifferent                    require:style,warning,inconclusive
No   CheckOther::checkIncompleteArrayFill                      require:warning,portability,inconclusive
No   CheckOther::checkIncompleteStatement                      require:warning
No   CheckOther::checkInterlockedDecrement                     require:windows-platform
No   CheckOther::checkInvalidFree
No   CheckOther::checkKnownArgument                            require:style
No   CheckOther::checkKnownPointerToBool                       require:style
No   CheckOther::checkMisusedScopedObject                      require:style,c++
No   CheckOther::checkModuloOfOne                              require:style
No   CheckOther::checkNanInArithmeticExpression                require:style
No   CheckOther::checkNegativeBitwiseShift
No   CheckOther::checkOverlappingWrite
No   CheckOther::checkPassByReference                          require:performance,c++
No   CheckOther::checkRedundantAssignment                      require:style
No   CheckOther::checkRedundantCopy                            require:c++,performance,inconclusive
No   CheckOther::checkRedundantPointerOp                       require:style
No   CheckOther::checkShadowVariables                          require:style
No   CheckOther::checkSignOfUnsignedVariable                   require:style
No   CheckOther::checkSuspiciousCaseInSwitch                   require:warning,inconclusive
No   CheckOther::checkSuspiciousSemicolon                      require:warning,inconclusive
No   CheckOther::checkUnreachableCode                          require:style
No   CheckOther::checkUnusedLabel                              require:style,warning
No   CheckOther::checkVarFuncNullUB                            require:portability
No   CheckOther::checkVariableScope                            require:style,notclang
No   CheckOther::checkZeroDivision
No   CheckOther::clarifyCalculation                            require:style
No   CheckOther::clarifyStatement                              require:warning
No   CheckOther::invalidPointerCast                            require:portability
No   CheckOther::redundantBitwiseOperationInSwitch             require:warning
No   CheckOther::warningOldStylePointerCast                    require:style,c++
No   CheckPostfixOperator::postfixOperator                     require:performance
No   CheckSizeof::checkSizeofForArrayParameter                 require:warning
No   CheckSizeof::checkSizeofForNumericParameter               require:warning
No   CheckSizeof::checkSizeofForPointerSize                    require:warning
No   CheckSizeof::sizeofCalculation                            require:warning
No   CheckSizeof::sizeofFunction                               require:warning
No   CheckSizeof::sizeofVoid                                   require:portability
No   CheckSizeof::sizeofsizeof                                 require:warning
No   CheckSizeof::suspiciousSizeofCalculation                  require:warning,inconclusive
No   CheckStl::checkDereferenceInvalidIterator                 require:warning
No   CheckStl::checkDereferenceInvalidIterator2
No   CheckStl::checkFindInsert                                 require:performance
No   CheckStl::checkMutexes                                    require:warning
No   CheckStl::erase
No   CheckStl::if_find                                         require:warning,performance
No   CheckStl::invalidContainer
No   CheckStl::iterators
No   CheckStl::knownEmptyContainer                             require:style
No   CheckStl::misMatchingContainerIterator
No   CheckStl::misMatchingContainers
No   CheckStl::missingComparison                               require:warning
No   CheckStl::negativeIndex
No   CheckStl::outOfBounds
No   CheckStl::outOfBoundsIndexExpression
No   CheckStl::redundantCondition                              require:style
No   CheckStl::size                                            require:performance,c++03
No   CheckStl::stlBoundaries
No   CheckStl::stlOutOfBounds
No   CheckStl::string_c_str
No   CheckStl::useStlAlgorithm                                 require:style
No   CheckStl::uselessCalls                                    require:performance,warning
No   CheckString::checkAlwaysTrueOrFalseStringCompare          require:warning
No   CheckString::checkIncorrectStringCompare                  require:warning
No   CheckString::checkSuspiciousStringCompare                 require:warning
No   CheckString::overlappingStrcmp                            require:warning
No   CheckString::sprintfOverlappingData
No   CheckString::strPlusChar
No   CheckString::stringLiteralWrite
No   CheckType::checkFloatToIntegerOverflow
No   CheckType::checkIntegerOverflow                           require:platform
No   CheckType::checkLongCast                                  require:style
No   CheckType::checkSignConversion                            require:warning
No   CheckType::checkTooBigBitwiseShift                        require:platform
No   CheckUninitVar::check
No   CheckUninitVar::valueFlowUninit
Yes  CheckUnusedFunctions::analyseWholeProgram
No   CheckUnusedVar::checkFunctionVariableUsage                require:style
No   CheckUnusedVar::checkStructMemberUsage                    require:style
No   CheckVaarg::va_list_usage                                 require:notclang
No   CheckVaarg::va_start_argument


Premium checkers
----------------
Not available, Cppcheck Premium is not used


Autosar
-------
Not available, Cppcheck Premium is not used


Cert C
------
Not available, Cppcheck Premium is not used


Cert C++
--------
Not available, Cppcheck Premium is not used


Misra C
-------
Misra is not enabled


Misra C++ 2008
--------------
Not available, Cppcheck Premium is not used

EDIT August 2024:
When I run cppcheck separately
$ cmake -G Ninja .. -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON
$ cmake --build . --parallel
$ cppcheck --project=compile_commands.json --enable=all --suppress=missingIncludeSystem --checkers-report=cppcheck.report --suppress=checkersReport --inline-suppr --std=c++17 --error-exitcode=1 -j 40

I get this (mostly yes):
$ cat cppcheck.report                                                                                                                                          

Critical errors
---------------
No critical errors, all files were checked.
Important: Analysis is still not guaranteed to be 'complete' it is possible there are false negatives.


Open source checkers
--------------------
Yes  Check64BitPortability::pointerassignment
Yes  CheckAssert::assertWithSideEffects
Yes  CheckAutoVariables::assignFunctionArg
Yes  CheckAutoVariables::autoVariables
Yes  CheckAutoVariables::checkVarLifetime
Yes  CheckBool::checkAssignBoolToFloat
Yes  CheckBool::checkAssignBoolToPointer
No   CheckBool::checkBitwiseOnBoolean                          require:style,inconclusive
Yes  CheckBool::checkComparisonOfBoolExpressionWithInt
Yes  CheckBool::checkComparisonOfBoolWithBool
Yes  CheckBool::checkComparisonOfBoolWithInt
Yes  CheckBool::checkComparisonOfFuncReturningBool
Yes  CheckBool::checkIncrementBoolean
Yes  CheckBool::pointerArithBool
Yes  CheckBool::returnValueOfFunctionReturningBool
Yes  CheckBoost::checkBoostForeachModification
No   CheckBufferOverrun::analyseWholeProgram
Yes  CheckBufferOverrun::argumentSize
Yes  CheckBufferOverrun::arrayIndex
Yes  CheckBufferOverrun::arrayIndexThenCheck
Yes  CheckBufferOverrun::bufferOverflow
Yes  CheckBufferOverrun::negativeArraySize
Yes  CheckBufferOverrun::objectIndex
Yes  CheckBufferOverrun::pointerArithmetic
No   CheckBufferOverrun::stringNotZeroTerminated               require:warning,inconclusive
No   CheckClass::analyseWholeProgram
No   CheckClass::checkConst                                    require:style,inconclusive
Yes  CheckClass::checkConstructors
Yes  CheckClass::checkCopyConstructors
Yes  CheckClass::checkDuplInheritedMembers
Yes  CheckClass::checkExplicitConstructors
Yes  CheckClass::checkMemset
Yes  CheckClass::checkMissingOverride
Yes  CheckClass::checkReturnByReference
Yes  CheckClass::checkSelfInitialization
Yes  CheckClass::checkThisUseAfterFree
No   CheckClass::checkUnsafeClassRefMember                     require:warning,safeChecks
Yes  CheckClass::checkUselessOverride
Yes  CheckClass::checkVirtualFunctionCallInConstructor
Yes  CheckClass::initializationListUsage
No   CheckClass::initializerListOrder                          require:style,inconclusive
Yes  CheckClass::operatorEqRetRefThis
Yes  CheckClass::operatorEqToSelf
Yes  CheckClass::privateFunctions
Yes  CheckClass::thisSubtraction
Yes  CheckClass::virtualDestructor
Yes  CheckCondition::alwaysTrueFalse
Yes  CheckCondition::assignIf
Yes  CheckCondition::checkAssignmentInCondition
Yes  CheckCondition::checkBadBitmaskCheck
No   CheckCondition::checkCompareValueOutOfTypeRange           require:style,platform
Yes  CheckCondition::checkDuplicateConditionalAssign
Yes  CheckCondition::checkIncorrectLogicOperator
Yes  CheckCondition::checkInvalidTestForOverflow
Yes  CheckCondition::checkModuloAlwaysTrueFalse
Yes  CheckCondition::checkPointerAdditionResultNotNull
Yes  CheckCondition::clarifyCondition
Yes  CheckCondition::comparison
Yes  CheckCondition::duplicateCondition
Yes  CheckCondition::multiCondition
Yes  CheckCondition::multiCondition2
Yes  CheckExceptionSafety::checkCatchExceptionByValue
Yes  CheckExceptionSafety::checkRethrowCopy
Yes  CheckExceptionSafety::deallocThrow
Yes  CheckExceptionSafety::destructors
Yes  CheckExceptionSafety::nothrowThrows
Yes  CheckExceptionSafety::rethrowNoCurrentException
No   CheckExceptionSafety::unhandledExceptionSpecification     require:style,inconclusive
Yes  CheckFunctions::checkIgnoredReturnValue
Yes  CheckFunctions::checkMathFunctions
Yes  CheckFunctions::checkMissingReturn
Yes  CheckFunctions::checkProhibitedFunctions
Yes  CheckFunctions::invalidFunctionUsage
Yes  CheckFunctions::memsetInvalid2ndParam
Yes  CheckFunctions::memsetZeroBytes
Yes  CheckFunctions::returnLocalStdMove
Yes  CheckFunctions::useStandardLibrary
Yes  CheckIO::checkCoutCerrMisusage
Yes  CheckIO::checkFileUsage
Yes  CheckIO::checkWrongPrintfScanfArguments
Yes  CheckIO::invalidScanf
Yes  CheckLeakAutoVar::check
Yes  CheckMemoryLeakInClass::check
Yes  CheckMemoryLeakInFunction::checkReallocUsage
Yes  CheckMemoryLeakNoVar::check
No   CheckMemoryLeakNoVar::checkForUnsafeArgAlloc
Yes  CheckMemoryLeakStructMember::check
No   CheckNullPointer::analyseWholeProgram                     require:unusedfunctions
Yes  CheckNullPointer::arithmetic
Yes  CheckNullPointer::nullConstantDereference
Yes  CheckNullPointer::nullPointer
Yes  CheckOther::checkAccessOfMovedVariable
Yes  CheckOther::checkCastIntToCharAndBack
Yes  CheckOther::checkCharVariable
Yes  CheckOther::checkComparePointers
Yes  CheckOther::checkComparisonFunctionIsAlwaysTrueOrFalse
Yes  CheckOther::checkConstPointer
Yes  CheckOther::checkConstVariable
No   CheckOther::checkDuplicateBranch                          require:style,inconclusive
Yes  CheckOther::checkDuplicateExpression
Yes  CheckOther::checkEvaluationOrder
Yes  CheckOther::checkFuncArgNamesDifferent
No   CheckOther::checkIncompleteArrayFill                      require:warning,portability,inconclusive
Yes  CheckOther::checkIncompleteStatement
No   CheckOther::checkInterlockedDecrement                     require:windows-platform
Yes  CheckOther::checkInvalidFree
Yes  CheckOther::checkKnownArgument
Yes  CheckOther::checkKnownPointerToBool
Yes  CheckOther::checkMisusedScopedObject
Yes  CheckOther::checkModuloOfOne
Yes  CheckOther::checkNanInArithmeticExpression
Yes  CheckOther::checkNegativeBitwiseShift
Yes  CheckOther::checkOverlappingWrite
Yes  CheckOther::checkPassByReference
Yes  CheckOther::checkRedundantAssignment
No   CheckOther::checkRedundantCopy                            require:c++,performance,inconclusive
Yes  CheckOther::checkRedundantPointerOp
Yes  CheckOther::checkShadowVariables
Yes  CheckOther::checkSignOfUnsignedVariable
No   CheckOther::checkSuspiciousCaseInSwitch                   require:warning,inconclusive
No   CheckOther::checkSuspiciousSemicolon                      require:warning,inconclusive
Yes  CheckOther::checkUnreachableCode
Yes  CheckOther::checkUnusedLabel
Yes  CheckOther::checkVarFuncNullUB
Yes  CheckOther::checkVariableScope
Yes  CheckOther::checkZeroDivision
Yes  CheckOther::clarifyCalculation
Yes  CheckOther::clarifyStatement
Yes  CheckOther::invalidPointerCast
Yes  CheckOther::redundantBitwiseOperationInSwitch
Yes  CheckOther::warningOldStylePointerCast
Yes  CheckPostfixOperator::postfixOperator
Yes  CheckSizeof::checkSizeofForArrayParameter
Yes  CheckSizeof::checkSizeofForNumericParameter
Yes  CheckSizeof::checkSizeofForPointerSize
Yes  CheckSizeof::sizeofCalculation
Yes  CheckSizeof::sizeofFunction
Yes  CheckSizeof::sizeofVoid
Yes  CheckSizeof::sizeofsizeof
No   CheckSizeof::suspiciousSizeofCalculation                  require:warning,inconclusive
Yes  CheckStl::checkDereferenceInvalidIterator
Yes  CheckStl::checkDereferenceInvalidIterator2
Yes  CheckStl::checkFindInsert
Yes  CheckStl::checkMutexes
Yes  CheckStl::erase
Yes  CheckStl::eraseIteratorOutOfBounds
Yes  CheckStl::if_find
Yes  CheckStl::invalidContainer
Yes  CheckStl::iterators
Yes  CheckStl::knownEmptyContainer
Yes  CheckStl::misMatchingContainerIterator
Yes  CheckStl::misMatchingContainers
Yes  CheckStl::missingComparison
Yes  CheckStl::negativeIndex
Yes  CheckStl::outOfBounds
Yes  CheckStl::outOfBoundsIndexExpression
Yes  CheckStl::redundantCondition
No   CheckStl::size                                            require:performance,c++03
Yes  CheckStl::stlBoundaries
Yes  CheckStl::stlOutOfBounds
Yes  CheckStl::string_c_str
Yes  CheckStl::useStlAlgorithm
Yes  CheckStl::uselessCalls
Yes  CheckString::checkAlwaysTrueOrFalseStringCompare
Yes  CheckString::checkIncorrectStringCompare
Yes  CheckString::checkSuspiciousStringCompare
Yes  CheckString::overlappingStrcmp
Yes  CheckString::sprintfOverlappingData
Yes  CheckString::strPlusChar
Yes  CheckString::stringLiteralWrite
Yes  CheckType::checkFloatToIntegerOverflow
Yes  CheckType::checkIntegerOverflow
Yes  CheckType::checkLongCast
Yes  CheckType::checkSignConversion
Yes  CheckType::checkTooBigBitwiseShift
Yes  CheckUninitVar::check
Yes  CheckUninitVar::valueFlowUninit
No   CheckUnusedFunctions::check                               require:unusedFunction
Yes  CheckUnusedVar::checkFunctionVariableUsage
Yes  CheckUnusedVar::checkStructMemberUsage
Yes  CheckVaarg::va_list_usage
Yes  CheckVaarg::va_start_argument


Premium checkers
----------------
Not available, Cppcheck Premium is not used


Autosar
-------
Not available, Cppcheck Premium is not used


Cert C
------
Not available, Cppcheck Premium is not used


Cert C++
--------
Not available, Cppcheck Premium is not used


Misra C
-------
Misra is not enabled


Misra C++ 2008
--------------
Not available, Cppcheck Premium is not used


Misra C++ 2023
--------------
Not available, Cppcheck Premium is not used


What did the report say?

BTW, cppcheck is open-source, so any mysteries can be resolved by looking at its source code.

@Sneftel, see my edit.

@heapunderrun, text messages and documentation can be confusing (for some), even in an open-source project.

I am not an expert on Cppcheck, but I do use it regularly.
My Understanding of The Problem
Your report file cppcheck.report suggests certain checks were not enabled with the --enable= flag. For example, you have a lot of require:style or require:warning checkers that you did not enable, like this one here No   CheckStl::checkMutexes                                    require:warning.
What The Cppcheck Source Code Suggests
From looking at the source code at https://cppcheck.sourceforge.io/devinfo/doxyoutput/cppcheckexecutor_8cpp_source.html on line 344 is the message that gets printed out in this situation. The function creates the list of checkers you enable and generates a report.
The Reason (Based on my opinion)
Now, some of the issues are related to the premium version (e.g. checkers for MIRSA, Cert C & C++), so I guess it's their way to push the premium version of cppcheck. At the same time, there are checks like inconclusive, which at least on my side causes my C++ compiler to complain about specific situations related to my code. The man pages for cppcheck also suggest that the --inconclusive flag can cause false positives. Therefore, I believe that this error is there to make us aware of all the features we are not using in cppcheck and that we as users need to verify whether or not we need those features.
How To Remove The Error
One way to remove the error is to add checkersReport to the --suppress= flag so that it can be suppressed. I would advise you to keep the report file though so that you can manually scan it to ensure that all the checkers you wanted to use, have been used.

Thank you for your comprehensive answer. Perhaps what is happening is that --enable=all (which is a flag I am using) is not really enabling all the checks in this version of cppcheck.

Hmmm, out of curiosity, what are your compiler options in CMake? For example, do you have -Wall, -Wconversion, -Werror, -Wextra enabled?
The reason I ask this is because the cppcheck.report that was generated is a report file that could contain false negatives as it's stated at the top of the file. On my side with those compiler options enabled I only have inconclusive warnings and some boolean bitwise operation related issues. However, they go away when I remove the --suppress=missingIncludeSystem flag.
Could you add those compiler flags and see if you get any compiler errors, pls?

I guess what I am getting at is that the --enable=all flag is performing correctly. But, cppcheck does not know if the issues it sees are worth showing the user because they might be false negatives, or it could be because of an option you set that forces cppcheck to analyze the code within the boundaries you describe it. So, it pumps it out to a log file for us to manually look at (e.g. cppcheck.report).

For example, this issue, No   CheckBool::checkBitwiseOnBoolean                          require:style,inconclusive is a result of adding --suppress=missingIncludeSystem to your configuration. If you remove that option, you will get a bunch of information checks that fail because cppcheck cannot find, oh, I don't know, pthread.h, for instance.

Apologies for the many comments.

I activate all the warnings I can, https://github.com/correaa/boost-multi/blob/master/test/CMakeLists.txt#L41-L861 and run cmake/cppcheck with these options: https://github.com/correaa/boost-multi/blob/6cc01914105b4a6966a684c21e7834274ddb1e5b/.gitlab-ci.yml#L144 . Sorry that I don't follow your explanation.

That is intersting. If you find time and feel like testing something a theory. Could you remove the --suppress=missingIncludeSystem flag run cppcheck and see if the majority of the No's turned into Yes's.

If I remove --suppress=missingIncludeSystem I get hundreds of errors, like this information: Include file: <vector> not found. Please note: Cppcheck does not need standard library headers to get proper results. [missingIncludeSystem]. Besides that, in the cppcheck.report file, I still see almost all checks as No. NOTE: this is on cppcheck 2.14.2 in MacOS which is not the original system I found this problem in.

See my edit, somehow the problem is running cppcheck as part of cmake build and not separately. This was not a problem before, AFAICT.

I added this output to Cppcheck as a part of the safety certification. It makes it visible for users if the expected checkers are executed or not.
In your case I am not sure why it only says that 4 checkers was executed that sounds very low. There could be some problem.
I am not sure how cmake executes cppcheck. But is there a "cppcheck build dir" that means the checkers are not executed? That would be fine.

It is as if enable-all is not working when I pass the command options through cmake,  cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_CXX_CPPLINT="cpplint;--quiet" -DCMAKE_CXX_CPPCHECK="cppcheck;--enable=all;--suppress=missingIncludeSystem;--inline-suppr;--std=c++17;--check-config;--error-exitcode=1". I do remember cppchecking many things, in the past at least.

Strange. I don't know what cmake does but Cppcheck should run more than 4 checkers even if you don't provide any --enable option. All the "error" checkers should be executed. To me it sounds like the file is skipped for some reason and then the "cppcheck build dir" was my best guess. Critical errors can cause this also but your report did say "No critical errors". If you add some bug in the file does cppcheck warn about it then, and will the checkers report still say that only 4 checkers are executed? if you add this line of code somewhere, cppcheck should warn : int dummy = 1000/0;

if the error is too obvious the compiler itself might complain before cppcheck. What I am going to do is to comment one of the cppcheck ignore “pragma”. This is all very strange.

When I run cppcheck separately (see my edit), the report says that most of the checks are active (as it should). Perhaps cmake broke the way it passes options to cppcheck and somehow is not passing "enable-all".
